# Change Value of Input Field when Clicking Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of Radio buttons which a user can click. Each Radio button should be able to populate 4 input fields with different values based on what button the user selected. In my case

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3

The Radio Button Values should correspond to the following input field values (Note I added the Option 1 values as default to the input field see [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkH6c/2/))

**Option 1**

- #inputValueA = Option 1 - Blue
- #inputValueB = Option 1 - Red
- #inputValueC = Option 1 - Yellow
- #inputValueD = Option 1 - Green

**Option 2**

- #inputValueA = Option 2 - Car
- #inputValueB = Option 2 - Bus
- #inputValueC = Option 2 - Train
- #inputValueD = Option 2 - Bike

**Option 3**

- #inputValueA = Option 3 - Cake
- #inputValueB = Option 3 - Sugar
- #inputValueC = Option 3 - Rice
- #inputValueD = Option 3 - Beer

What I am looking for is to try and get help to figure out what Javascript to write to populate the different input fields each time a radio button is pressed based on the above values.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkH6c/2/) here to see a demo.

My Code is

```
    <!-- Radio Buttons -->
<div data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button id="Option1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Option 1</button>
    <button id="Option2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 2</button>
    <button id="Option3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 3</button>
</div>

<!-- Input Button 1 -->
<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tag"></i></span>
    <input id="inputValueA" type="text" value="Option 1 - Blue" name="">
</div>

<!-- Input Button 2 -->
<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tag"></i></span>
    <input id="inputValueB" type="text" value="Option 1 - Red" name="">
</div>

<!-- Input Button 3 -->
<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tag"></i></span>
    <input id="inputValueC" type="text" value="Option 1 - Yellow" name="">
</div>

<!-- Input Button 4 -->
<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tag"></i></span>
    <input id="inputValueD" type="text" value="Option 1 - Green" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: They are not radio buttons

Comment: There's no JavaScript in that jsfiddle so it's hard to tell what the problem is. Or are you just asking for somebody to write code for you?

Comment: @PSR, yes they are according to Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Comment: @Pointy, I wrote above I am looking for some help with the JS. I am honestly not sure where to start with JS, but do HTML / CSS. So yes, i am looking for some help on here where people generally give help to these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fkH6c/

```
$(function() {
    var values = [
        ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
        ['Car', 'Bus', 'Train', 'Bike'],
        ['Cake', 'Sugar', 'Rice', 'Beer'],
    ];

    $('.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
        var index = $(this).index();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $('#inputValue' + 'ABCD'[i]).val('Option ' + (index+1) + ' - ' + values[index][i]);
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkH6c/5/)

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function(){
if($(this).text() =="Option 1"){
     $('#inputValueA').val('Option 1 - Blue')
     $('#inputValueB').val('Option 1 - Red')
    $(' #inputValueC').val('Option 1  -Yellow');
     $('#inputValueD').val('Option 1 - Green')
}
else if($(this).text() =="Option 2"){
     $('#inputValueA').val('Option 2 - Car')
     $('#inputValueB').val('Option 2 - Bus')
    $(' #inputValueC').val('Option 2 - Train');
     $('#inputValueD').val('Option 2 - Bike')
}
else{
     $('#inputValueA').val('Option 3 - Cake')
     $('#inputValueB').val('Option 3 - Sugar')
    $(' #inputValueC').val('Option 3 - Rice');
     $('#inputValueD').val('Option 3 - Beer')
}});
```

Comment: thanks man, will accept as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Yes the above answer is nice than my answer